Where does the term "reflection" come from?
Earlier today, I was asked why a motion of the plane that fixes a line of points is called a reflection and I was stumped for an answer.
The best explanation I can think of is that the image of a shape under a reflection will be that shape's "mirror image" (this is mentioned on the Wikipedia page). If you look in a mirror, the image you see is a reflection of the real world. That said, in two dimensions terms like "flip" seem more intuitive.
This leads to my question:

Where, historically, does the analogy of "reflection" arise in mathematics?


You'll get detailed answers for a question like this at HSM, and quickly.

Should I delete it here before I post it there?

I would, people don't like cross-posting the same thing on different parts of SE. I think there is a mechanism to transfer a post, but I don't know it.

According to the Wikipedia article titled "Reflection (mathematics)", some mathematicians do use "flip" instead of "reflection", so your intuition is not incorrect. As for why "reflection" is used at all, I can't find any reliable sources, but I suspect it comes from the mirror analogy. Overall, it seems that the better question would be: how did the word "reflection" come to refer to a mirrored image? But then that would no longer be a question for MSE...

I will leave the question here for a week, and if I get no answers with reliable sources I will ask again on HSM.
